# How to send JQuery value to php SESSION

Tags: php, jquery, input

I try to send JQuery value to SESSION, here is the code(MVC)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#tbody th").click(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        $("#"+id).focus();
        $("#send").val(id);
    });
});
```

In HTML:(form.php)

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="choix" value="retour">
<input type="hidden" id="send"  name="send" value="">
<input type="submit" name="choix" value="edit" formaction=".../edit/$_SESSION['id']">"
<input type="submit" name="choix" value="delete" formaction="......."
```

In controller:

```
public function editAction(){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $this->_request->post('send')? $this->_request->post('send') : '';
    (...)
}
```

When the page submit (send), I have the SESSION['id'], but in the URL, I have "localhost/.../edit/", that mean the SESSION value do not send to URL. 
How to send the value in the same time? 
Thanks for your answer

Comment: $this->_request->post does not look like a plain PHP. Is that some PHP framework? please include that in your question

Comment: I use the MVC PHP

Comment: Yes but, what PHP MVC framework are you using?

Comment: Can you try to submit AJAX request

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $value
```

is not a correct way to set the session ID,
please use

```
$value = $this->_request->post('send')? $this->_request->post('send') : '';
session_id($value);
session_start();
```

which should create a new session using your new id
as described on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php